# Using yarn workspaces in project - workspace unable to resolve dependencies hoisted to project

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with the following file structure:

```
package.json
node_modules
yarn.lock
modules
  - moduleA
    - package.json
    - node_modules
  - moduleB
    - package.json
    - node_modules
```

In my top-level `package.json` I have:

```
"workspaces": ["modules/*"]
```

moduleB has no dependencies, at least not yet. When I ran `yarn install` in the root directory:

- Almost all of moduleA's dependencies were installed in the root-level `node_modules`
- VSCode is unable to resolve these dependencies inside of moduleA's source code
- When I `cd` into moduleA and run a script, I get `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` errors for the hoisted dependencies.

Is there a way I can configure my project so that I can access hoisted dependencies from inside moduleA? I was unable to find anything about this in the Yarn dependencies. I have used `nohoist` as a workaround, but this is not optimal - I want to run my modules inside of their own directories and still be able to access shared dependencies.

Yarn version: `1.22.4`